# Where should I put code instead of a top level testbench?

Tags: system-verilog

In my OVM testbench.sv, I have added code to the bottom of the module to force and release internal signals. However, this code takes up space. What options do I have for putting the code into a different file? Should I put the code in another .sv and bind it the testbench?

Comment: You need to explain further what the problem with the fact that it takes up _space_. It's going to take the same space no mater where you put it, and using the **bind** construct will add even more complexity.

Comment: I figured that the testbench would be for instantiating the DUT and connecting up interfaces and not for any logic. The logic needed for this forcing and releasing of internal signals belonged in an initial block.
A co-worker suggested that this code would better fit in the base_test as it something that would be done in all tests.

Comment: So I guess I was looking for locations for where this code could or should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide this code from the top-level module, you could put it an include file to be `` `include ``d  by the top-level testbench module.

You could put your code in a separate top-level module. All of the hierarchical references to internal DUT signals would start from the other top-level module that instantiates the DUT.

You could also put your code into a module or group of modules and bind it into the DUT module. If you can separate your code into groups for different blocks within the DUT, then you can bind each module into that block. That will save you repeating the same hierarchical paths over and over.